# Webview no ios fica em branco

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Olá estou começando a programar para ios, e não estou conseguindo rodar uma webview, sempre fica em branco, veja o codigo :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://conecode.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Mas sempre que rodo no emulador, fica em branco a parte da webview, alguem sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: O código para carregar a WebView está correto. Provavelmente o problema está na criação da WebView. Como você está criando ela (nib, storyboard, ...)? Postar o código completo facilitaria a identificação do problema.

Comment: eu apenas arrastei a webview, para o storyboard , e declarei la no @property

Comment: Primeiramente verifique se a propriedade foi declarada como IBOutlet: @property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView. Depois verifique a conexão do storyboard com o código. Clique com o botão direito sobre a view e veja se existe um Outlet para essa propriedade.

Comment: Olá, ao ver o outlet, nao aparece nada, ai clico em add, e aparece um view, mas nao entendi, ainda continua em branco

Comment: Para esclarecer o que pode parecer óbvio, mas apenas para desencargo de consciencia. Você declarou a `ViewController` como controladora da sua tela no storyboard?

Comment: Não entendi , como vejo isso?

Comment: Tem como alguem criar um projeto de exemplo com uma webview e me passar? ficaria muito grato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após criar a *view* no seu **Storyboard** e os arquivos **ViewController**, você faz um vínculo entre estes dois, lá no **Storyboard**, selecione a barra **Utilities > Identity inspector** e informe a *ViewController*, que no meu exemplo chamei de `MinhaWebViewController`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Volte no arquivo de implementação (**.m**), e logo abaixo da `@interface` declarei o *outlet*:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

Perceba que por enquanto esse *outlet* não tem vínculo nenhum (note o pequeno círculo ao lado sem preenchimento):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para fazer esse vínculo, vá no **Storyboard**, com a tecla **control** pressionada, arraste o ícone amarelo até sua `UIWebView` e selecione a propriedade criada anteriormente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora você pode voltar no arquivo de implementação (**.m**) e notar que o pequeno círculo agora está preenchido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode conferir também ao selecionar sua `UIWebView` no **Storyboard** e em **Utilities > Connections inspector**. Há uma conexão inserida para este *outlet*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pronto, basta fazer sua implementação para carregar a *URL*:

```
NSString *fullURL = @"http://conecode.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Se ainda assim quiser o projeto inteiro, coloquei disponível no **[Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1o0NIBAU7UjMnl6NWN2RUxZcjg/view?usp=sharing)** por enquanto.

Comment: deu tudo certo, nao precisei baixar seu projeto.Muito obrigado

Comment: ola cara, eu rodei usando swift, e no emulador funciona mas no meu iphone4 não, no iphone ele fica em branco a webview, o que pode ser lembrando q estou ultilizando o xcode6 e swift. obrigado

Comment: Rodou na mesma versão do iOS que está no iPhone? No iPhone provavelmente é a versão 7.1, última que ele possui, certo? É preciso observar as versões. Se for preciso, crie uma nova pergunta colocando seus códigos para melhor entendimento.

Comment: Não lembro a versão, mas rodei no iphone4S do emulador, e rodou normalmente. No  iphone fica em branco, criei exatamente como está nesse video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rva9ylPHi2w

Comment: Voce acha que o swift, não roda no iphone 4?

Comment: Com certeza o Swift é compatível no iPhone 4, resta saber o que há de errado na implementação. Você implementou os métodos de *delegate* do `UIWebView`, `didFailLoadWithError` por exemplo? Ou o `webViewDidFinishLoad` para ver se chega até o fim?

Comment: não implementei, ao rodar, ele roda o splash padrao com o nome da aplicação, e a webview fica em branco, o que tenho que fazer?

Comment: Acredito que agora seja mais prático você criar uma nova pergunta, especificamente para Swift, que é um caso diferente deste. Coloque toda sua implementação com detalhes para podermos entender e ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Para uma solução em Swift, recomendo usar o [CSafariWebKit](https://github.com/dmandarino/CSafariWebKit)

No seu arquivo

```
import CSafariWebKit
```

E no ViewController que quiser chamar a WebView

```
let vc = SafariViewController(url: url, barTintColor: nil, tintColor: nil)
vc.presentSafari(fromViewController: self, whenDidFinish: nil)
```

Use as cores do seu app para uma melhor experiência.